# AttributeError: module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute '_is_coroutine'

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, django-channels

I'm deploying a django app made with django channels using nginx, gunicorn and daphne. During deployment when I run **python manage.py makemigrations**, I get the following error. Could it be because the python version on my local machine was 3.7 and on remote ubuntu server is 3.5?

```
  from cryptography import x509
/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.5 support will be dropped in the next release of cryptography. Please upgrade your Python.
  from cryptography import x509
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/apps.py", line 20, in ready
    monkeypatch_django()
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/hacks.py", line 10, in monkeypatch_django
    from .management.commands.runserver import Command as RunserverCommand
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 11, in <module>
    from channels.routing import get_default_application
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 10, in <module>
    from channels.http import AsgiHandler
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 152, in <module>
    class AsgiHandler(base.BaseHandler):
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 214, in AsgiHandler
    @sync_to_async
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 375, in sync_to_async
    return SyncToAsync(func, thread_sensitive=thread_sensitive)
  File "/home/ubuntu/django/virtualenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 262, in __init__
    self._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine
AttributeError: module 'asyncio.coroutines' has no attribute '_is_coroutine'
```

Comment: Does it happen with 3.5 locally? With 3.7 on the server?

Comment: Locally I have 3.7 and it works fine but on server its 3.5 and this is happening. I'm wondering if its because of the different versions. What do you think?

Comment: I’m asking if you’ve tried running the remote version locally or the local version remotely. I don’t know if that’s the problem, but you generally don’t want to develop and deploy using two different versions, so using the same version in both places would be a good first debugging step.

Comment: Yes, Thank you! It was an issue with different versions on my local machine and on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

The error is beacause of `asgiref` package that uses `asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine` attribute since version `3.2.2`.

You can install asgiref 3.2.1 and this problem doesn't happen.

```
pip install asgiref==3.2.1
```